# Generic repository: how to filter eager-loaded navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

this is my generic respoitory that im using, as the title states I want to know how to filter the navigation properties.

```
public IEnumerable<T> Query(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _objectSet.Where(e => !e.IsDeleted);            

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
var viewModel = new StudentViewModel();
        viewModel.Students= _unitOfWork.Students.Query(
            includeProperties: "Subjects, Instructors");
```

Now my problem is I want to add a .Where(e => !e.IsDeleted) 
to [Subjects] and [Instructors] using the repository.

Thanks

EDIT:
according to Ladislav, currently it is not possible (also mentioned here in msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx)

```
Can i just use this instead?
viewModel.Subjects = viewModel.Students.Where(i => i.StudentID ==Id.Value)
                     .Single().Subjects.Where(e => !e.IsDeleted);
```

My only worry is that the query may return lots of records with isDeleted==true. Sure the code I posted as an alternative works, I just don't want to pull the data that I don't need even though I can filter it using the above code

Comment: Could you explaine what do you mean "add a .Where(e => !e.IsDeleted) to [Subjects] and [Instructors] using the repository."

Comment: @voo I think she wants to filter the included properties.

Comment: @samantha07 Could you then show us query.Include() method?

Comment: Eager loading in EF doesn't support filtering.

Comment: @tschmit007, yes you're right

Comment: @voo, include method is already posted. this is the equivalent to: db.Students.Include("Subjects");

Comment: @ladislav, thanks, yo always answer my question here. can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL supports this scenario using the LoadWith DataLoadOption. The example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx shows the simple case that EF does support with the Include statement.

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders);
db.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

However, unlike EF, LINQ to SQL also supports the following:

```
dlo.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.ShippedDate is Null);
```

If you feel this is an important enhancement scenario for EF, consider voting for it at http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method.

For now, your best option is to project your filter in the Select clause, but that gets tricky with a generic repository.